# Default value in textfield using picker view

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uipickerview

I am new to ***iOS*** i need to display `objectAtIndex(0)` in *textfield* using *`uipickerview`* .while run the app textfield empty after selection in picker view only value can displayed in textfield i need initially textfield not be empty.

*`viewdidload`* code:

```
    pktStatePicker  .delegate = self;

    pktStatePicker  .dataSource = self;

    [ pktStatePicker  setShowsSelectionIndicator:YES];

    txtText.inputView =  pktStatePicker  ;

    // Create done button in UIPickerView


    UIToolbar*  mypickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 56)];

    mypickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;

    [mypickerToolbar sizeToFit];


    NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];

    [barItems addObject:flexSpace];


    UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(pickerDoneClicked)];

    [barItems addObject:doneBtn];


    [mypickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];


    txtText.inputAccessoryView = mypickerToolbar;
```

*picker view delegates:*

```
- (void) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component

{
     NSLog([arrmsg1 objectAtIndex:row]);
    txtText.text = (NSString *)[arrMsg objectAtIndex:row];

}
```

Comment: sonu single doubt when u load the data in arrMsg

Comment: ya arrMsg data is there@Anbu.Karthik

Comment: can you show the code of where you append the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set like on your `ViewDidLoad`, but ensure once your `arrMsg.count!=0`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
txtText.text = (NSString *)[arrMsg objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

**choice-2**

or when you append the data in arrMsg after that call like

```
if (arrMsg.count >0)
{
txtText.text = (NSString *)[arrMsg objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

there after continue your work asuseual